# What type of architecture is backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In this [tutorial here](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/3.html), 3 out of many, I see that they call the view from the model.

In all the diagrams I've seen, there should be a controller mediating this interaction.

I'm not complaining, but are they breaking a strict MVC pattern?

As far as tracking dependencies goes, a controller should depend upon the model and the view.

The model and the view should be independent from each other and the controller.

Does Backbone break the MVC pattern?

Comment: `var item = new Item();`

Comment: top hit on google claims it is MVC...http://backbonetutorials.com/why-would-you-use-backbone/

Comment: They do admit there View is more like a controller.....http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-mvc

Comment: Calling a view/controller from a model should be avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry Hiro, but I'm going to have to disagree with you.  Backbone.js CAN be very MVC, but it all depends on how you implement it.  The problem is that most of the backbone.js examples out there only show view events being bound to methods in that view, but there are 2 ways to get around this to complete the MVC pattern.

The first is to simply replace all events/buttons within a view to hashbang URL links that the router can easily pick up, or you can make your event method definition call the appropriate method in the controller and pass along the parameters.

And as ertume said, you should never be invoking a view from a model.

Comment: I'm just saying that if you want true MVC, you can easily accomplish this.  If you want to use the default of the view taking on part of the responsibility of the controller, you can do that too.  That's the greatest thing about backbone.js is how flexible it is.

Answer (score 4):

Backbone is not an MVC by any means.  The View acts as a contoller defeating the purpose of the MVC separation of concerns.

Also the (View/Controller) contains logic which in a strict MVC would be kept in the model.

**From the FAQ**
http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-mvc

> How does Backbone relate to "traditional" MVC?  Different
>   implementations of the Model-View-Controller pattern tend to disagree
>   about the definition of a controller. If it helps any, in Backbone,
>   the View class can also be thought of as a kind of controller,
>   dispatching events that originate from the UI, with the HTML template
>   serving as the true view. We call it a View because it represents a
>   logical chunk of UI, responsible for the contents of a single DOM
>   element.

Comment: +1 and my own thoughts on what Backbone is / is not: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/23/backbone-js-is-not-an-mvc-framework/